# Dynamically set div with leaflet side-by-side plugin

Tags: leaflet

I want to set the left margin of a div by the position of the slider from the [side-by-side plug in](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side). It looks to be possible as the `dividermove` event built into the plug-in, but I haven't been able to figure out a method to feed that into the CSS for my div.

In the jsfiddle below, I basically want to dynamically set the left margin `#year05` and `#year15` using `dividermove`. I tried setting the `#year05` class to inherit `left` from `leaflet-sbs-divider` but couldn't get it to work and I imagine is not the proper way to do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/x8r0pvg1/45/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to position some text that follows the slider of Leaflet Side-by-Side plugin.

In that case, instead of trying to re-position your text / div on `"dividermove"` event, a very simple solution would be to append your div into the slider / divider itself, so that when the plugin adjusts the position of the latter, your div follows along automatically:

```js
var yearsEl = document.getElementById('years'); // your div
document.querySelector('.leaflet-sbs-divider').appendChild(yearsEl);
```

Then you can center your div on the divider with your method of choice, e.g. using CSS:

```css
#years {
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8r0pvg1/47/